# Configure Couchbase 2.2 to use short hostname

Tags: erlang, couchbase, hostname, erl

I need to configure Couchbase 2.2 to use **short hostname**.

Currently I am using Couchbase 2.0.1 and in this case the solution was easy:

1. Set Short hostname in `/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/ip` and  `/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/ip_start` files.
2. Change `extra="-name ns_1@$ip"` for `extra="-sname ns_1@$ip"` in `_start()` function into `/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server`. This parameter was used to run erl (`-run ns_bootstrap -- $extra`)

This steps allows me to configure the node with the **short hostname** and create the cluster based on these.

In Couchbase 2.2 I can't do that because *erl* runs using *babysitter*. I try to configure babysitter to use short hostname but I couldn't make it work...

The servers were deployed in an a private Virtualization environment that only handle short hostname.

Each node has 2 ips, one public and one private. If I run a `ping` command from itself i get their *private IP* and I run ping a command from any other node I get their *public IP*.

For example, if I have one node:
myhost-00 (private IP: 192.168.8.170 public IP: 10.254.171.29)

from itself:

```
$ ping myhost-00
PING myhost-00 (192.168.8.170) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

from other node:

```
$ ping myhost-00
PING myhost-00 (10.254.171.29) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a workaround:

Firstly, I don't modify any of the Couchbase files.

Secondly, I add a fake domain to my short hostname in each /etc/hosts file. In the file I append the private IP for the current node and the public IP for other nodes with the fake domain.

```
For example, assuming I have 2 hosts: 
myhost-00 (private IP: 192.168.8.170 public IP: 10.254.171.29) 
myhost-01 (private IP: 192.168.8.168 public IP: 10.254.171.30)

myhost-00 /etc/hosts file:
...
192.168.8.170 myhost-00.mydomain
10.254.171.30 myhost-01.mydomain
...

myhost-01 /etc/hosts file:
...
10.254.171.29 myhost-00.mydomain
192.168.8.168 myhost-01.mydomain
...
```

Finally, I create de cluster using the hostnames with the fake domains (myhost-00.mydomain and myhost-01.mydomain)

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Couchbase does not allow the use of short names for the node name.  There are ticket updates that discuss and confirm this situation.

For long hostnames, you will find steps to use hostname at http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#couchbase-getting-started-hostnames and http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#using-hostnames, depending on version.  You can leverage hostname when a cluster is created, a node is added to a cluster, or you can change from an IP address to a hostname via a REST API command.  See the doc for full details.

Comment: Hi, Couchbase uses full hostnames by default. I neet to use short hostnames which is not allowed by default given its *erl* settings. In  version 2.0.1. I solved that in version 2.0.1 (as I said in the question), but in version 2.2 couchbase began to use babysitter and this changed the way to configure erl.

Comment: If I try to set a short hostname to a node I got this message: "Requested name hostname is not allowed: short names are not allowed. Couchbase Server requires at least one dot in a name"

Comment: Hi Diego.  My apologies for misunderstanding your question.  Shortnames are not supported.  The code explicitly traps this scenario so it cannot be configured.  I updated the reply above to reflect this situation.

Comment: No problem! Thanks!I was reviewing the code of ns_server and babysitter and I figured out a workaround :D